# Would like to bulk populate a custom field via CSV import

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, import

I have a custom plugin and it includes an import/export section. I have added a new ACF field called serial_number_issued. I would like to bulk populate this using a CSV import file. However, I'm not too sure what I need to add to the code to get this working. I've added serial_number_issued to the list array but what do I need to add to update the page:

```
list( $system_name, $system_id, $status, $serial_number, $serial_number_issued ) = $data;
                        $status = ( $status == '-' ) ? 'Generated' : $status;
                        $status = ( ( $status == 'Generated' ) && ( $system_id != '-' ) ) ? 'Allocated' : $status;

                        // If serial exists, update. If not, insert new
                        $post = get_page_by_title( trim( $serial_number ), ARRAY_A, $sha_wreg_module_slug );
                        if ( isset( $post['post_type'] ) && ( $post['post_type'] == $sha_wreg_module_slug ) ) {
                            $serial_id = $post['ID'];

                            // Update system info
                            if ( ( $system_name != '-' ) && ( $system_id != '-' ) ) {
                                $system = get_post( $system_id );
                                update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', array( 'id' => $system->ID, 'name' => $system->post_title ) );
                            }

                            // Update status
                            update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', $status );
```

This is the page with the Serial Number Issued column that I want to update with the CSV file import

[image]
So we want to be able to bulk update the field with the answer Yes.

Here is the full code for the import.

```
switch ( $action ) {

    // Import cards from CSV
    case 'import':
        if ( isset( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'import_csv' ] ) && ( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'import_csv' ]['error'] == 0 ) ) {
            $row = 1;
            if ( ( $handle = fopen( $_FILES[ $sha_wreg_prefix . 'import_csv' ]['tmp_name'], "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
                while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, "," ) ) !== FALSE ) {
                    $row++;
                    if ( $row > 2 ) {
                        list( $system_name, $system_id, $status, $serial_number, $serial_number_issued ) = $data;
                        $status = ( $status == '-' ) ? 'Generated' : $status;
                        $status = ( ( $status == 'Generated' ) && ( $system_id != '-' ) ) ? 'Allocated' : $status;

                        // If serial exists, update. If not, insert new
                        $post = get_page_by_title( trim( $serial_number ), ARRAY_A, $sha_wreg_module_slug );
                        if ( isset( $post['post_type'] ) && ( $post['post_type'] == $sha_wreg_module_slug ) ) {
                            $serial_id = $post['ID'];

                            // Update system info
                            if ( ( $system_name != '-' ) && ( $system_id != '-' ) ) {
                                $system = get_post( $system_id );
                                update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', array( 'id' => $system->ID, 'name' => $system->post_title ) );
                            }

                            // Update status
                            update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', $status );

                            wp_update_post( $serial_id . 'serial_number_issued', $serial_number_issued );


                        } else {
                            $data = array(
                                'post_title'    => $serial_number,
                                'post_type'     => $sha_wreg_module_slug,
                                'post_status'   => 'publish'
                            );

                            $serial_id = wp_insert_post( $data );

                            // Update system info
                            if ( ( $system_name != '-' ) && ( $system_id != '-' ) ) {
                                update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'system', array( 'id' => $system_id, 'name' => $system_name ) );
                            }

                            // Update status
                            update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', $status );

                        }
                    }
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }
            $_SESSION['sha-wreg'] = array(
                'class'     => 'notice-success',
                'message'   => 'Serials successfully imported'
            );
        }
    break;
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here … Are you trying to update the post _title_? The title is not _meta_ data, so you’d need to use `wp_update_post` for that.

Comment: So I have a page that shows the content for the following system_name, system_id, status, serial_number, serial_number_issued. I've added the serial_number_issued field and want to be able to add a value for this field via a CSV import. The above code is a snippet to what we have already for the import. I wanted to add a bit of code to update the serial_number_issued field for each item. I thought I would just need to add the following: update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', $status ); and update it for the serial_number_issued value

Comment: That seems about right, @emslouise81.

Comment: I tried adding update_post_meta( $serial_id, $sha_wreg_prefix . 'status', $status ) and changing it to update_post_meta( $serial_id . 'serial_number_issued', $serial_number_issued ) but it didn't work

Comment: Of course, you have a typo there: shouldn't `update_post_meta( $serial_id . 'serial_number_issued', $serial_number_issued )` be `update_post_meta( $serial_id, 'serial_number_issued', $serial_number_issued )` instead? (Notice I changed the `.` with a `,` there.)

Comment: I changed the . with a , so have this update_post_meta( $serial_id, 'serial_number_issued', $serial_number_issued ); . However, this still isn't working. I have imported a CSV file with that field filled out and it hasn't updated the corresponding field in the Wordpress page